# getting libssh2 to compile with php5

Tags: php, centos

I'm trying to get php5 to compile using libssh2. ./configure --help gives me no option on how to include the libssh files. also, if i try to phpize libssh, i get an error telling me no config.m4 file exists in the highest src directory of the project. That would be because there is no config.m4 file anywhere in the project for phpize to use.

How can I get libssh2 to compile in to php5.2.6 ?

This is on a new centos 5.3 64 bit OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I learned that it is easier not to compile libssh2 into php at all. just do a PECL install of it and add it in as an extention module.

pecl install ssh2-0.11.0

The funny dialog that pops up means you need to enter your libssh2 install path. Press 1 to get into the path entry dialog.

Then its off to the races!!

Comment: note, you can't just do pecl install ssh2 because the pecl release is still beta and it will try to get standard channel if you don't add the major and minor version nums on.